# javascript/html inheritance: called method of an object can't access this variables

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, events

Hello first of all i excuse myself for the title beeing pretty generic, but i honestly don't know how to summarize my question if not like that.
I'm creating a pretty complex project in javascript, a language i'm not too used to use. I usually develop in c/c++.
I want to assign an event to a DOM object (in this example is a div element with id "test").
There are 2 classes A and B. The object of class A has a reference to an object of class B.
I add the event from class A.
I would expect 2 possibilities: 1) the this in the listener refers to the div element, and there's no objxxxx property; 2) this refers to the object that creates the listener and the output will be "0".
Both Firefox and Chromium debuggers show me that b.test() is executed. and the console.log output is "undefined".
How is it possible?

```js
class A {
    objxxxx;
    constructor(obj) {
        this.objxxxx = obj;
    }
    create() {
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", this.objxxxx.test );
    }
}
class B {
    a;
    value;
    constructor() {
        this.value = 0;
        this.a = new A(this);
        this.a.create();
    }
    test() {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}

let b = new B();
```

```html
<div id="test">click</div>
```

Comment: Hi, your first guess is correct. The `div` also lack a `value` property, which is why you get `undefined`. Otherwise you would have got the `div` DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

You have in your B class:

```js
test() {
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

Here, `this.value` actually means the property `value` of the instance of
class A.
If you put `console.log("test")`, it works fine.
To fix your problem, try this:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener(
  "click", 
  this.objxxxx.test.bind(this.objxxxx) 
);
```

Note: code not tested.

Answer (score 0):

while jacob answer is right for creating function but its not answer what is `this` in your code, `this` is refer to the current element, it is because there are no class initialization and because the element is `div` there is no or you can't use `.value`

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.textContent);
  console.log(this.value);
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", test);
```

```html
<div id="test">click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all people that answered.
Every answer pointed me a bit more in the right direction to find the correct answer.

In javascript the keyword "this" is not relative to the object it's written into, but it's bound to the execution context.
In my question as Jacob wrote the context of "this" is object A, therefore will not find "this.value". I wrongly expected that the keyword "this" did work as c/c++/java referring to the instance of the object.
In such cases i need to change the execution context with apply/call/bind.